# Avoid file collision laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-filesystem

I wanted to know how do I avoid file collision in Laravel. Lets say I have two users with the same filename and both gets affected because one of them changed  the file how do I go about avoiding that. Here is my code

```
 $file = $request->file('file');
      $myfilename = $vid->getClientOriginalName().uniqid();
      $mypath = $file->storeAs(
'video',
$myfilename);
      $location = public_path('/allvids',$myfilename);
      $file->move($location);
      $file->profile = $myfilename;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should be saving files with generated filenames. There's nothing wrong with storing the actual filename in the database, and then serving it as that, but in general, you should generate one. There's a few ways to do so.

[time()](http://php.net/time) use a unix timestamp

[uniqid()](http://php.net/uniqid) generate a unique ID

Personally, I'd suggest the second.

Also, you're doing;

```
$file->store('video', $myFilename)
```

What you want is;

```
$file->storeAs('video', $myFilename)
```

The `store()` method will use the original filename of the file.

Comment: I tried uniqid so many times it doesn't work it still changes the other person file. I am going to update my question and showed you what I did.

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look

Comment: I tried the storeAS many times too. Still nothing has changed.

Comment: Then I don't know what the problem is. If you're using `uniqid()` and `storeAs()` there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I don't know either. I just updated my code. Am I like doing something wrong cause this crazy.